# How to get an handle and enumerate Registry path : "\REGISTRY\A\"?

Tags: c++, windows, registry, native, registrykey

I am trying to get a handle to  the Registry hive "\REGISTRY\A{GUID}" and enumerate the keys under that handle. I been searching for hours but still hasn't got a clue on how to open or enumerate it.Please help me get to the correct API to do so. Btw,  RegOpenKeyEx() and RegEnumKeyEx() doesn't work, I tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question after reading [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611291/mysterious-native-a-registry-key-with-path-registry-a

Comment: this work on win8.1, but on win10 when we try open "\REGISTRY\A\"  we got access denied

Comment: @drescherjm that thread was the stating point for me. there was no clear information on how to access "\REGISTRY\A\". Btw im new to c++.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the reply. I have no problem accessing it using kernel debugger but i want to access it programmatically

Comment: I been trying it in windows 10. I also ran 'procmon' on windows 10 and noticed that some application are able to access \Registry\A\{<Random UUID>}.  Actually i havn't tried it on windows 8.1. If i use NtOpenKeyEx() ObjectName as "\REGISTRY\A\" it fails but if i use "\REGISTRY" as ObjectName im able to open the key but NtQueryValueKey() fails. Am i missing something?

Comment: I figured that much but i dono which file i must load into the hive to get to \Registry path

Comment: Hi @eryksun sorry for the long delay and thank you for your help. i am now able to load in to "\Registry\a\{GUID}" path and access it. This is what i was looking for thanks. If you could post this as answer i can mark it as solution. Again thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications with handles for "\REGISTRY\A\{GUID}" paths have either called [`RegLoadAppKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724886) or [`NtLoadKeyEx`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntregapi_8h.html#aa4c6abc699a9c60acbfdc0fd4a229215). `RegLoadAppKey` loads a private application hive at an automatically generated path, "\REGISTRY\A\{GUID}". It returns a handle for the hive's root Key, and subkeys can be enumerated, created and opened relative to this handle.

It used to be possible to open "A" relative to a handle for "\REGISTRY" and enumerate its subkeys. This is no longer allowed in Windows 10. I assume access is restricted in the Configuration Manager's parse procedure for Key objects, `CmpParseKey`. However, you can still inspect this Key using a kernel debugger with commands such as `!reg q \REGISTRY\A`.